# Download images while extracting tweets from twitter using python

Tags: python-2.7, twitter, data-extraction

I am working in Python to extract tweets from a given twitter handle. I came accross methods which are able to download the tweets but I want to download the images attached to them too. Can anyone suggest any idea or existing method which would help?

Comment: I tried to extract images from the links attached in the tweets but they have various images in them and the image attached in tweet might be any of those

Comment: Are you using the Twitter REST API?  Within the tweet json is an [entities](https://dev.twitter.com/overview/api/entities) object that contains a 'media' json array.  All of the inline images in the tweet should be in there.

Comment: I am using tweepy API